# Show Bullets on images in IOSlider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using the jquery ioslider by default it is using the prev and next button to move to next slide but i need the bullets on each slide so that user can see how many slides are in the slider like below screen shot

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about this slider: https://iosscripts.com/iosslider/? If not, how about a link to the plugin you are using and maybe the code you have so far?

Comment: YEs I am using the same slider as you add in command i.e ioscripts.com/iosslider.please help?

Comment: Great, please show us the HTML markup and script you currently have, or even better, create a jsFiddle that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Also, as this is a commercial plugin, have you tried contacting them for support?